# To all you Game lovers

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge

> If BACKGAMMON is reverse of CONNECT4
>
> And
>
> OTHELLO is BACKGAMMON and MONOPOLY together
>
> Then
>
> TRIVIAL PURSUIT is OTHELLO and **what** together?

The "**what**" is of course a sit down game!

Could be more than one answers.

Comment: I like this riddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, So I think I have the pattern and a possible answer

> You add up all the spaces on the playing board, 42 in connect4, 24 in backgammon (24 backwards is 42 so it works) 64 in othello, 40 in monopoly(24 + 40 = 64 it still works) and 73 in trivial pursuit. So a possible answer could be tic tac toe(73 - 64 = 9 and tic tac toe has nine squares)?

Comment: Think simple @Yout Ried. Really Simple.

Comment: Check it out now

Comment: Now please edit your answer to fully explain how you got there

Comment: @DEEM ok fine i did